# Edit and Update data for specific row/column of csv file MFC

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, mfc

How to edit and update data in csv file MFC. I am able to read data from csv file using ReadString().

```
void ModifyCSVFile(){
     .....
}
```

Comment: How should someone be able to tell what you want to do with your data ? That's your own job.

Comment: @Blacktempel I think I have provided sufficient information and here I am looking for hints not for solution.

Comment: If you program with MFC, shouldn't you be able to read and write a file too ? That's basic C++. Read data in a `std::vector` (likely 2d for a CSV file) from a CSV-parser, access it, edit it, write it back to the file. If that's not it, I don't get what you want...

Comment: @Blacktempel it was useful. Is there any direct api to update the csv data.

Comment: Just google for CSV parser, there are lots of around. You could also write your own parser if you have a hour or two.

Comment: @ Blacktempel thank u for help. I have written my own csv parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you ReadString(), you modify it to your liking and write to another file using WriteString(). When you are done, delete the original file and rename the new one. 
If you simply want to replace some symbols with the same number of different symbols, you can do that in place.